# Text-overflow: ellipsis in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

When I using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in IE I have problem with two long words:

**In Chrome it looks like:**

> firstlongword1...
>
> secondlongword2...

**In IE:**

> firstlongword1...
>
> secondlongword2 //word cropped, but dots not present

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.orange {
    color: #f58026;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="orange" title="12 12">first_verylongworddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd second_verylonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
```

If somebody had a problems with it, please help.
Or please say me if exist other method to fix it.

Comment: Try to set `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/css/textOverflow.htm

Comment: that is not possible.. I mean showing ellipsis on two lines.. maybe it is working fine in chrome because of some `-webkit` related css which you might have used.

Comment: @gearsdigital If I will use `white-space: nowrap;` text won't be multiline. Usually text is one-line, but user have opportunity to write 50 chars for first name and for last name and if it happen text will be multiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the CSS specification it would appear that Chrome (and Firefox) are displaying the ellipsis correctly, IE, it seems is behind the curve. Goto http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#text-overflow0 and scroll down to **Example 9** to see demonstrations on how `text-overflow:ellipsis;` should be rendered.

As such it would seem that the only way to get a similar result in IE is to wrap the words in their own elements:

```css
.orange {
    color: #f58026;
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.orange span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="orange" title="12 12">
    <span>first_verylongworddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span> 
    <span>second_verylonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
</span>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fL6za37f/2/

Comment: Thanks, it works, but if first and last names will be short it won't be displayed in one-line. Will try use JS.

Comment: @rtm7777 Please see my edit, by using `display: inline-block;` and `min-width: 100%;` it is possible to allow short names to be displayed on one line.

Comment: It works! thank you very much! Spent the entire day in an attempt to make it nice and without js. Thanks again)

Answer (score 0):

Append ellipsis when text overflows containing element supports globally, though you can use jQuery ellipsis plug-in http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/ or below (got it long time ago so forget the source) which is based container width:

```
$.fn.ellipsis = function(){
    return this.each(function() {
        var el = $(this);`
        if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden"){
            var text = el.html();
            var multiline = el.hasClass('multiline');
            var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                .hide()
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .css('overflow', 'visible')
                .width(multiline ? el.width() : 'auto')
                .height(multiline ? 'auto' : el.height())
                ;
            el.after(t);
            console.log('Container width: t.width(): ' + t.width() + ' text: '+ text);
            console.log('Container width: t.height(): ' + t.height());
            function height() { return t.height() > el.height(); };
            function width() { return (t.width()+2) > el.width(); };
            var func = multiline ? height : width;
            while (text.length > 0 && func()){
                text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                t.html(text + "...");
            }
            el.html(t.html());
            t.remove();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to put " white-space: nowrap; " in the orange class

```css
.orange {
    color: #f58026;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="orange" title="12 12">first_verylongworddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsfgdsdfgdfgsdfhdfhsdfhsdfhdddddddddd second_verylonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
```

Comment: Its a one line solution